# python check if json.dumps is possible

Tags: python, json

is it possible to check if a value is able to be "json.dumps"d 
like `json.dumping.possible(code)` with a boolean output?
I would be thankful for help

Comment: try to dump it, and catch the error if occurs -- `try/except` that is the pythonic way

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: `import this` for more

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no way to check if an object is serializable to a `json` format. However, you can (even if it is not really [*EAFP* compliant](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)) try and if it fails go for a fallback process:

```
try:
    json.dumps(my_object)
except TypeError:
    print("Unable to serialize the object")
```

A way to be sure would be to [implement your own `JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) if you are entirely sure of the data processed.